# Python pandas to ensure each row based on column value has a set of data present, if not add row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am organising AWS resources for tagging, and have captured data into a CSV file. A sample output of the CSV file is as follows. I am trying to make sure that for each resource_id, there is a dataset of tag_key that I need to ensure is present. This dataset is

tag_key

```
Application
Client
Environment
Name
Owner
Project
Purpose
```

I'm new to pandas, I've only managed to get the CSV file read as a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "z.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_name, names=['resource_id', 'resource_type', 'tag_key', 'tag_value'])

print (df)
```

CSV file

```
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Environment,Development
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Name,Database Files
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Project,Application Development
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Purpose,Web Server
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Environment,Production
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Owner,Fast Company
```

I am expecting the output to be as follows

```
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Environment,Development
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Name,Database Files
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Project,Application Development
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Purpose,Web Server
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Client,
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Owner,
vol-00441b671ca48ba41,volume,Application,
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Environment,Production
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Owner,Fast Company
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Application,
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Client,
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Name,
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Project,
i-1234567890abcdef0,instance,Purpose,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: @M_S_N I've seen the post, but it's not the same, I've modified my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use multindexes, `from_product`, and `renindex`:

```
taglist = ['Application',
           'Client',
           'Environment',
           'Name',
           'Owner',
           'Project',
           'Purpose']

df_out = df.set_index(['resource_id','tag_key'])\
           .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['resource_id'].unique(), taglist],
                                              names=['resource_id','tag_key']))

df_out.assign(resource_type = df_out.groupby('resource_id')['resource_type']\
                                    .ffill().bfill()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
              resource_id      tag_key resource_type                tag_value
0   vol-00441b671ca48ba41  Application        volume                      NaN
1   vol-00441b671ca48ba41       Client        volume                      NaN
2   vol-00441b671ca48ba41  Environment        volume              Development
3   vol-00441b671ca48ba41         Name        volume           Database Files
4   vol-00441b671ca48ba41        Owner        volume                      NaN
5   vol-00441b671ca48ba41      Project        volume  Application Development
6   vol-00441b671ca48ba41      Purpose        volume               Web Server
7     i-1234567890abcdef0  Application      instance                      NaN
8     i-1234567890abcdef0       Client      instance                      NaN
9     i-1234567890abcdef0  Environment      instance               Production
10    i-1234567890abcdef0         Name      instance                      NaN
11    i-1234567890abcdef0        Owner      instance             Fast Company
12    i-1234567890abcdef0      Project      instance                      NaN
13    i-1234567890abcdef0      Purpose      instance                      NaN
```

Comment: @m3appy Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?

Comment: just found that rows which do not have data that match the 'taglist' will get abandoned, is there a way to "add and not remove"?

Comment: tried that got this `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (6,) `

Comment: Can you create a small dataset that generates this error?  Create a new question indicate the error and the code generating this error.  I need to be able to duplicate the error inorder to make a suggestion.

Comment: Hi ScottBoston I had to do something like this `taglist = np.unique(np.concatenate((taglist,taglist_present),0))`. I'll start a new question as I think this has deviated

Answer (score 0):

To make a slightly simpler example. I have dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [[1, 2], [3, 5], [1, 2], [5]]})
```

Returning

```
   a       b
0  1  [1, 2]
1  1  [3, 5]
2  2  [1, 2]
3  2     [5]
```

With required b's: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Then we need to find out what we 'already have'. This we do:

```
def flatten(lsts):
    return [j for i in lsts for j in i]

df_new = df.groupby(by=['a'])['b'].apply(flatten)
```

Returns:

```
a
1    [1, 2, 3, 5]
2       [1, 2, 5]
```

Now we need to list the columns we are missing and add those:

```
df_new = df_new.reset_index()
lst_wanted = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for row in df_new.itertuples():
    for j in lst_wanted:
        if j not in row.b:
            df = df.append({'a': row.a, 'b': j}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Returning:

```
   a       b
0  1  [1, 2]
1  1  [3, 5]
2  2  [1, 2]
3  2     [5]
4  1       4
5  2       3
6  2       4
```

Comment: I like this method, it appends rows and not abandons them